# How can I fix this: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'float'?

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to use the row values to get the `C_vel` values.

The code:

```
wb = op.load_workbook('Canopy\Scripts\De Velliers.xlsx')
ws = wb ['Sheet1']                         
for row in ws.rows:
    for cell in row:
        print(cell.value)
        print "----------"
        C_vel = ws.rows / (A_c * rho)
        print "C_vel: ", C_vel
```

The error message:

```
TypeError                      
Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\Fraixxer Fraiz\Canopy\scripts\franis 1.py in <module>()
     26         print(cell.value)
     27         print "----------"
---> 28         C_vel = ws.rows / (A_c * rho)
     29         print "C_vel: ", C_vel
     30 

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'float'
```

Comment: `ws.rows` is a tuple, which you cannot divide by the float `A_c*rho`. Print them out in each loop so you can see what's going on. It's hard to help you any further because I'm not sure what the desired result for `C_vel` is.

Answer (score 1):

You can not do mathematical operations on tuples. Using numpy you could convert the tuple to an array first. Mathematical operations can be performed on numpy arrays.

```
    import numpy as np
    wb = op. load _ workbook ('Canopy\Scripts\De Velliers.xlsx')
    ws = wb ['Sheet1']                            
    for row in ws . rows:
        for cell in row:
            print(cell. value)
            print "----------"
            C_vel = np.array(ws. rows)/ (A_c * rho)
            print "C_vel:",C_vel
```

Comment: You can't do list/float either.